# Python subprocess.call() apparently not working with psexec

Tags: python, subprocess, psexec

I am having an issue executing remote processes with `subprocess.call()` and psexec. I am using the following syntax for executing the process remotely with `subprocess.call()`:

```
def execute(hosts):
    ''' Using psexec, execute the script on the list of hosts '''
    successes = []

    wd = r'c:\\'
    file = r'c:\\script.exe'
    for host in hosts:
        res = subprocess.call(shlex.split(r'psexec \\%s -e -s -d -w %s %s ' % (host,wd,file)), stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None)
        if res == 0:
           successes.append(host)   
        else:
            logging.warning("Error executing script on host %s with error code %d" % (host, res))

    print shlex.split(r'psexec \\%s -e -s -d -w %s %s ' % (hosts[0],wd,file))
    return successes
```

As you can see, as part of my troubleshooting, I am printing the `shlex.split()` output to ensure that it is what I want. This print statement gives:

```
['psexec', '\\HOSTNAME', '-e', '-s', '-d', '-w', 'c:\\', 'c:\\script.exe']
```

Which is what I would expect. Unfortunately, when I run it, I get an error saying:

```
PsExec could not start \GN-WRK-02:
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Directly after this, I run the psexec command with the exact syntax that the program should be running it with (judging by the `shlex.split()` output) and it works completely fine. My syntax is:

```
psexec \\HOSTNAME -e -s -d -w c:\\ c:\\script.exe
```

Any ideas why this wouldn't be working? If it matters the execute function is being called through multiprocessing's `map()` function on two or 3 host lists.

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `\\` double slash in front of the hostname is just **one** slash; it is doubled to escape the slash.

You can see this in the `shlex.split()` output:

```
['psexec', '\\HOSTNAME', '-e, '-s', '-d', '-w', 'c:\\', 'c:\\script.exe']
```

note that `\\` before the hostname is just the two backslashes, *just like in the `c:\\` filename value.*. If you print just that value you see that the backslash at the sart is just one character:

```
>>> print '\\HOSTNAME'
\HOSTNAME
>>> '\\HOSTNAME'[0]
'\\'
>>> '\\HOSTNAME'[1]
'H'
```

That's because `shlex.split()` is a POSIX tool, not a Windows tool, and it interprets the `\\` in the raw string as an escape too; if you are using that tool, double the slashes again:

```
shlex.split(r'psexec \\\\%s -e -s -d -w %s %s ' % (host,wd,file))
```

An alternative may be to *disable* POSIX mode, but I am not entirely certain how that would interplay with Windows:

```
shlex.split(r'psexec \\%s -e -s -d -w %s %s ' % (host,wd,file), posix=False)
```

Comment: How come the double slash is printed when i print shlex.split(...) then? I do see that there is only one slash in the error I am given though. Hopefully the fix is this easy! Appreciate the answer

Comment: Ahhhh okay, I see why it is interpreting the slashes differently. I will try this now. Thank you so much!